# rails button_to is not setting the class correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My code:

```
<%= button_to 'Login', {:type => 'submit', :class => 'submit'} , {}%>
```

I want to end up with this:

```
<input type='submit' value='submit' class=submit/>
```

but what I'm getting is:

```
<input type=submit value=submit/>
```

how to set the class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The HTML options are the third parameter according to [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to). Try this:

```
<%= button_to 'Login', {}, { :type => 'submit', :class => 'submit' } %>
```