# Css class is not applying on button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a button below:

```
<table align="center" width="50%">
<tr>
   <td style="color: #212121;">
    <div class="button">
         <%= button_to "Search", {:class => "buttonhome" } %>
    </div>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am applying buttonhome class i.e below

```
.buttonhome
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    font-family: Arial;

    background-color: transparent;
    border-style: none;
    font: white;
}
```

But its not applying on the button. Kindly suggest me. Waiting for reply. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= button_to "Search", {action: "search"}, {class: 'buttonhome'} %>
```

possible duplicate [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123884/rails-button-to-applying-css-class-to-button) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061652/rails-button-to-is-not-setting-the-class-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
div.button .buttonhome
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    font-family: Arial;

    background-color: transparent;
    border-style: none;
    font: white;
}
```

also check if your css is loading fine and your button has the class buttonhome.

Answer (score 0):

The html_option is 3rd parameter of button_to according to documentation

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to

so use this

```
<%= button_to 'Search', {}, { :class => "buttonhome" } %>
```